# ¿PHP tiene una función que haga lo contrario de array_sum, que reste los valores de un array?

Tags: php

Si quiero sumar todos los valores de una array, puedo usar la función [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php) de PHP:

```
$someValues=array(10,3,1,0) ;
var_dump(array_sum($someValues));
```

***Salida:***

```
int(14)
```

Es como hacer: `10+3+1+0`.

Si quiero sustraer cada valor en forma contigua, creo que debería existir una función `array_sub` en PHP que haga esto: **`10-3-1-0`**

**¿Está documentado en alguna parte por qué existe `array_sum` y no `array_sub`?**

**¿Cómo puedo crear mi propia función `array_sub`?**

Comment: Y si haces -1*array_sum($someValues)  ?

Comment: @Fly daría `-14`. En el ejemplo debería dar: `6`.

Comment: es una cuestión matemática, el array sum empieza sumando desde 0: `0 + 10 + 3 + 1 + 0`, un array sub que se comporte igual empezaría restando desde 0: `0 - 10 - 3 - 1 - 0`, de ahí que sea equivalente el comentario de @Fly : sumar y negar multiplicando, ó directamente `0 - array_sum`

Comment: array_sum hace lo mismo la diferencia es que a los numeros tienen un `-` si colocas tu numeros en negativos lo restara de la misma forma

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_sub($arr) {

    while (!$primero = array_shift($arr) AND count($arr) > 0) {

    }

    $sum = array_sum($arr);

    return $primero - $sum;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Pero no funciona como se esperaría. Supongamos que tengo un array así: `$someValues=array(0,3,1,0)`, en ese caso la primera operación daría como resultado un `-3` y eso trastoca el resultado final. En ese caso habría que hacer algo como `3-1-0`, dando como resultado `2`.

Comment: Describe entonces todas las casuísticas que quieres contemplar, porque sino es muy complicado darte una respuesta certera.

Comment: Fly, lo que quiero es sustraer todos los valores del array, pero si el primer valor es cero ignorarlo porque alteraría el resultado. Quisiera algo parecido a `array_sum`. Viendo las dificultades del cero y de posibles números negativos ahora empieza a tener sentido que no exista dicha función en PHP ¿?

Comment: modificado para que los ceros iniciales no se tengan en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar la función `array_reduce` que toma una función y la aplica a cada elemento del array de forma iterativa para llegar a un único valor

```
function sub($carry, $item)
{
    $carry = $carry ? $carry - $item : $item;
    return $carry;
}

echo array_reduce($someValues, "sub", "El array no contiene datos"); // Si está vacío informa el 3er parámetro como mensaje
```

Espero que haya sido de ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Tampoco me funciona. Si suponemos este array: `$someValues=array(10,2,3,1,1);`, me da `-17`, cuando debería dar `3`.

Comment: hay que capturar y saltarse el primer valor (si no arranca  0 - 10 - 2...)

Comment: Disculpame, ahí edité la respuesta para que considere el caso que andás necesitando

Answer (score 0):

una alternativa restando al primer elemento la suma del resto

```
<?php
    $someValues=array(10,3,1,0) ;
    var_dump(implode(' + ',$someValues), array_sum($someValues));

    function array_sub($arr=NULL){
        $res = 0;
        if (!empty($arr)) :
            $primero = array_shift($arr);
            $res = $primero - array_sum($arr);
        endif;
        return $res;
    }

    var_dump(implode(' - ',$someValues), array_sub($someValues));

    $otro = [10, -2];
    var_dump(implode(' + ', $otro), array_sum($otro));
    var_dump(implode(' - ', $otro), array_sub($otro));
```

resultado:

```
string(14) "10 + 3 + 1 + 0"
int(14)
string(14) "10 - 3 - 1 - 0"
int(6)
string(7) "10 + -2"
int(8)
string(7) "10 - -2"
int(12)
```